# If $F[F(x)] = f(s)$, then what is $F[\frac{d}{dx}F(x)]$?

Tags: fourier-transform

Suppose $F[F(x)] = f(s)$, then need to find $F[\frac{d}{dx}F(x)]$. Here $F$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ i.e. $$F(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-2\pi iat}dt.$$
Any idea how to proceed will be very helpful.

Comment: Is this for sure what you meant to ask?  For any nice function $f$ we have $F(F(f))(s) = f(-s)$, so $F(F(x))(s) = -s$.

Comment: Is $F$ the F.T. of $f$ or the other way?

Comment: It was given that $F$ is the F.T. of $f$